# find entries that have the same name and less than 15 mins exists

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I use for my Nodejs query.
I have to check if a customer exists who is not older than 15 Minutes from now. For this I use:

```
        const iskunde = await kunden.findAll({
            where: {
              kunde: user,
              created_at: {
                [Op.lte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)"),
              },
            },
            raw: true,
          });        
          if(Array.isArray(iskunde) && iskunde.length) {
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }
```

After debugging now more than 2 hours I try to find some help here. As my understanding from documenation the syntax I use have to work. It reports always false. Do I have a bug inside the time query of 15 Minutes.

Rule is: Report kunde if time create_at is not older than 15 minutes.

#####Update
@mplungjan gave me the hint about the array. Chnaged now to findAll

But the query seems to be wrong. Sample:
Current time: `2022-08-01 19:14:4`
But the query also reported the entry: id

```
id |kunde    |created_at
809|KingMarci|2022-08-01 18:22:15
```

as result. It is definitly older than 15 minutes. Any Idea?

Comment: Please code `if (something that can be true is true) return true; else return false;` as `return something that can be true`

Comment: @mplungjan I do not understand you comment. A Sequelize database query will always give an Array. The common way do get findOne Data is iskunde[0]. So ifthere is no array, the query was not successful.  FindOne will always give an Arry of size length 1.

Comment: @mplungjan got it. FindOne returns an object not an array. Changed now to findAll.

Comment: Tillykke. You can delete the question